# why is the firstname and lastname field not saved in django-registration?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-registration, django-users

I have included field for `firstname` and `lastname` in `django-registration` form. but After registration my `admin page` is not showing the registered `first name` and `last name`, it is blank, but the `username` and `email address` are shown.

Please read the `docstring` as provided in `source code` below:

Here is the code for `RegistrationForm` from `django-registration`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Form for registering a new user account.

    Validates that the requested username is not already in use, and
    requires the password to be entered twice to catch typos.

    Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
    need, but should avoid defining a ``save()`` method -- the actual
    saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
    registration backend.

    """
    required_css_class = 'required'

    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                max_length=30,
                                label=_("Username"),
                                error_messages={'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label=_("Password"))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label=_("Password (again)"))

    first_name=forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                max_length=30,
                                label=_("first name"),
                                error_messages={'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    last_name=forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                max_length=30,
                                label=_("last name"),
                                error_messages={'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})

    def clean_username(self):
        """
        Validate that the username is alphanumeric and is not already
        in use.

        """
        existing = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        if existing.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("A user with that username already exists."))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']

    def clean(self):
        """
        Verifiy that the values entered into the two password fields
        match. Note that an error here will end up in
        ``non_field_errors()`` because it doesn't apply to a single
        field.

        """
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

EDIT:

```
    def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):
            username, email, password,first_name,last_name = (cleaned_data['username'], cleaned_data['email'], cleaned_data['password1'],
                                        cleaned_data['first_name'],cleaned_data['last_name'])
            if Site._meta.installed:  # @UndefinedVariable
                site = Site.objects.get_current()
            else:
                site = RequestSite(request)
            new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
                                                                        password, site, first_name,last_name)
            signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                         user=new_user,
                                         request=request)
            return new_user


def create_inactive_user(self, username, email, password,
                             site, send_email=True,first_name=None, last_name=None):
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        if first_name:
            new_user.first_name=first_name
        if last_name:
            new_user.last_name=last_name
        new_user.is_active = False
        new_user.save()

        registration_profile = self.create_profile(new_user)

        if send_email:
            registration_profile.send_activation_email(site)

        return new_user
    create_inactive_user = transaction.commit_on_success(create_inactive_user)
```

Comment: What version of Django you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

You could change `create_inactive_user` on `Registration/Models.py` to look like this...

```
def create_inactive_user(self, username, email, password,
                         site, send_email=True, first_name=None, last_name=None):
    """
    Create a new, inactive ``User``, generate a
    ``RegistrationProfile`` and email its activation key to the
    ``User``, returning the new ``User``.

    By default, an activation email will be sent to the new
    user. To disable this, pass ``send_email=False``.

    """
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    new_user.is_active = False
    new_user.first_name = first_name
    new_user.last_name = last_name
    new_user.save()

    registration_profile = self.create_profile(new_user)

    if send_email:
        registration_profile.send_activation_email(site)

    return new_user
```

Notice it is now accepting `first_name` and `last_name`. Also notice the `new_user.first_name = first_name` and `new_user.last_name = last_name`

Then on `Registration/backends/default/views.py` you'll want `register` to look like this...

```
def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):

    username, email, password, first_name, last_name = cleaned_data['username'], cleaned_data['email'], cleaned_data['password1'], cleaned_data['firstname'], cleaned_data['lastname']
    if Site._meta.installed:
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
    else:
        site = RequestSite(request)
    new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email, password, site, first_name, last_name)
    signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                 user=new_user,
                                 request=request)
    return new_user
```

Notice the `firstname` (which is how your form is getting it) and `first_name` (which is what it is being stored as then passed to the `create_inactive_user`.

Comment: Correct, the database is already setup to hold the firstname and lastname. Also, the answer above assumed you were using simple and not default. Which one are you using? If you aren't specifying "simple" in the urls. You're most likely using default.

Comment: I am using default. but it has a different call which is `new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
                                                           password, site)`

Comment: Haha, I've never made so many edits to my answer. I've updated it again and that should work for you.

Comment: my last name is not getting registered and  displayed in admin (so I guess it is not saved). but first name is registered and displayed on admin. I have pasted in edit above

Answer (score 0):

The reason is not working now after correcting as teewuane mentioned is because of `method signature`

consider this:

```
def create_inactive_user(self, username, email, password,
                         site, send_email=True, first_name=None, last_name=None):
```

but in the `register method`above you make a call:

```
new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email, password, site, first_name, last_name)
```

since `send_email=True` is the `default` value, what ever `first_name` gets, is passed in as `send_email` and `last_name` gets passed to `first_name`. hence you will have `last_name` as `None`.

The fix is simple. Just change the method signature as follows:

```
def create_inactive_user(self, username, email, password,
                             site, first_name=None, last_name=None, send_email=True):
```